# Android autocompletetextview wrap text with badge

Tags: android

I want to create an autocompletetextview which wraps its text like the Messenger app of FaceBook. If user has selected from suggestions then the text is wrapped like a badge. I want to achieve something like that.

However this is what I've tried:

```
public void changeOption(AutoCompleteTextView text) {
    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}

public void toggle(AutoCompleteTextView text) {
    text.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
}

textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() > 0) {
                changeOption(textView);
            } else {
                toggle(textView);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });
```

This wraps the entire background, but I want to wrap only the text. Any ideas how to achieve that? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setup AutoCompleteTextView like this..

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="2dp"
```